# Jtree from folder path saved in database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtree

i want to create a jtree from folder path saved in database like
TestFolder/ABCD/CDEF/ghml
TestFolder/ABCD/THYU/UVWZ iam saving only the path not parent structure so when i try to create tree structure it works fine for single path(TestFolder/ABCD/CDEF/ghml) i want buid a complete tree struture if any one have idea please help

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] a) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new JTreeEvents());
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

enter code here

 class JTreeEvents extends JPanel {

private String driver = new String("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
private String url = new String("jdbc:mysql:);
private String user = new String("root");
private String password = new String("128");
private Connection dbCon;
List<String> arrayList;
Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map;
String[] folderArr;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
java.sql.Statement s;
ResultSet r;
DefaultMutableTreeNode top;
DefaultTreeModel dt;
DefaultMutableTreeNode trees;
DefaultTreeModel model;
DefaultMutableTreeNode child, subchild;
//tree  

JTree jtree;

JTextField jtf;

public JTreeEvents() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    Class.forName(driver);
    dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    s = dbCon.createStatement();
    r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM project p where p.name='MyFolder4'");
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    map = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
    Hashtable<String, Object> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    MutableTreeNode parent;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode parentnode;
    TreePath path = null;
    while (r.next()) {
        arrayList.add(r.getString("path"));
    }

    for (String str : arrayList) {
        if (str != null) {
            folderArr = str.split("/");
            String projName = str.split("/")[0];
            root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(projName);
            model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
            jtree = new JTree(model);

            for (int i = 0; i < folderArr.length; i++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(folderArr[0]);
                } else {
                    path = jtree.getNextMatch(folderArr[i - 1].toString(), 0, Position.Bias.Forward);
                    if (path != null) {
                        System.out.println(path);
                    }
                    parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (MutableTreeNode)                                                            path.getLastPathComponent();                                       

                }  
enter code here
                model = (DefaultTreeModel) jtree.getModel();
                model.insertNodeInto((DefaultMutableTreeNode) new                           DefaultMutableTreeNode(folderArr[i]), parent, parent.getChildCount());

                model.reload();
                jtree.expandPath(path);
            }
        }

    }

    int v = ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    int h = ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtree, v, h);

    add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jtf = new JTextField("", 20);
    add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jtree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            doMouseClicked(me);
        }
    });
}
enter code here
void doMouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    TreePath tp = jtree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
    if (tp != null) {
        jtf.setText(tp.toString());
    } else {
        jtf.setText("");
    }
}
      private TreePath find(DefaultMutableTreeNode root, String s) {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> e = root.depthFirstEnumeration();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = e.nextElement();
    if (node.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
        return new TreePath(node.getPath());
          }
 }
 return null;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that do not work in your code. First the code to build the tree can be much simplified like this:

```
public JTreeEvents() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  // ... fill the array list from the database ..

  for (String path: arrayList) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode currentParent = root;
    String[] pathComponents = path.split("/");
    for (String comp: pathComponents) {
      DefaultMutableTreeNode child = findChild(currentParent, comp);
      if (child == null) {
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(comp);
        currentParent.add(child);
      }
      currentParent = child;
    }
  }

  model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
  jtree = new JTree(model);

  // ... build the rest of the GUI components
}

private DefaultMutableTreeNode findChild(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, String s) {
  for (int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent.getChildAt(i);
    if (s.equals(child.getUserObject())) return child;
  }
  return null;
}
```

The second thing is that JPanel comes by default with no layout, so you need to add one explicitely, before adding any component to it:

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

So the full code of JTreeEvent becomes, after getting rid of all the unused variable declarations:

```
public class JTreeEvents extends JPanel {
  private String driver = new String("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  private String url = new String("jdbc:mysql:");
  private String user = new String("root");
  private String password = new String("128");
  private Connection dbCon;
  List<String> arrayList;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  java.sql.Statement s;
  ResultSet r;
  DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("/");
  DefaultTreeModel model;
  JTree jtree;
  JTextField jtf;

  public JTreeEvents() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(driver);
    dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    s = dbCon.createStatement();
    r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM project p where p.name='MyFolder4'");
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (r.next()) {
      arrayList.add(r.getString("path"));
    }

    for (String path: arrayList) {
      DefaultMutableTreeNode currentParent = root;
      String[] pathComponents = path.split("/");
      for (String comp: pathComponents) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = findChild(currentParent, comp);
        if (child == null) {
          child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(comp);
          currentParent.add(child);
        }
        currentParent = child;
      }
    }

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    jtree = new JTree(model);

    int v = ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    int h = ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtree, v, h);
    add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jtf = new JTextField("", 20);
    add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jtree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        doMouseClicked(me);
      }
    });
  }

  void doMouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    TreePath tp = jtree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
    if (tp != null) {
      jtf.setText(tp.toString());
    } else {
      jtf.setText("");
    }
  }

  private DefaultMutableTreeNode findChild(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, String s) {
    for (int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
      DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent.getChildAt(i);
      if (s.equals(child.getUserObject())) return child;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I tested it without the database stuff, by manually adding paths to the array list in my code, and it works nicely:

[image]

Comment: how to display this dyanamically generated jtree or tree model in ui ?is there any tree structure in jsp or any simple tree model in javascript or jquery please suggest please help